# The value of $\frac{(-1+i\sqrt 3)^{15}}{(1-i)^{20}}+\frac{(-1-i\sqrt 3)^{15}}{(1+i)^{20}}$ is

Tags: complex-numbers

The expression can be written as

$$\frac{(2w)^{15}}{(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})^{20}}+\frac{(2w^2)^{15}}{(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4})^{20}}$$

Where *w* is a cube root of $1$
$$=2^{15}\left[\frac{w^{15}}{\cos 5\pi - i\sin 5\pi}+\frac{w^{30}}{\cos 5\pi + i\sin 5}\right
]$$

$$=2^{15}[-1-1]$$
$$=-2^{16}$$

The answer given is $-64$. What is going wrong?

Comment: You omited $\sqrt 2$ in denominators.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your calculations a bit easier by realizing that the expression is $z + \bar z = 2\Re{(z)}$ with $z = \frac{(-1+i\sqrt 3)^{15}}{(1-i)^{20}}$.

Now, using

- $-1+i\sqrt{3} = 2e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}$
- $1-i = \sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi i}$

you get

$$2\Re{(z)} = 2\cdot \Re \left( \frac{2^{15}}{2^{10}e^{-\pi i}}\right) = -2^6 = -64$$

Comment: Didnt understand the last line. How is it $2Re(\frac{2^15}}{2^{10}e^{-\pi i}})$. (I don’t know why this isn’t working)

Comment: @Aditya : Note that $e^{it}$ is $2\pi$-periodic for $t\in \mathbb{R}$. So, you have 
$$z = \frac{\left( 2e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i} \right)^{15}}{\left( \sqrt{2}e^{-\frac{1}{4}\pi i} \right)^{20}} = \frac{2^{15} \overbrace{e^{10\pi i}}^{=e^0=1}}{2^{10} \underbrace{e^{-5\pi i}}_{=e^{-\pi i} = -1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$(-1+i\sqrt{3})^{15}=32768$$ and $$(1-i)^{20}=-1024$$